# Enviar correos VBA

Tags: vba, email

He creado una macro que envía correos a distintos destinatarios recorriendo una columna con un iterador i donde se encuentran estas direcciones de correo.

Funciona todo correcto pero cuando pongo más de una dirección de correo en la misma celda de la que lee las direcciones de email, me da error.

El código es el siguiente:

```
         .To = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i + 1, 13).Value
         .cc = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i + 1, 14).Value 
         .Subject = "Send email"   'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja").Range("W2").Value
         .Body = "This is the body"
         .Attachments.Add ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja1").Cells(i + 1, 24).Value
         .Send
        
         End With
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nunca nos mostraste cómo tienes las direcciones en la misma celda. La clave es que sea una lista separada por punto y coma `;`

`pepito@email.com;juanito@hohoho.com;maria@cosas.org"`

Si se asigna eso a `.To`, va a funcionar como esperas